# Servo is jittery and moves back and forth when it should be still

Tags: gpio, opencv, servo

(Sorry about formatting) I am trying to write an opencv program to track the color red. So far it works okay, but the servo is jittery and when the object is still and centre the servo moves back and forth. I have a 470uf capacitor and an external power supply. Any help to make it smoother would be a godsend!

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray 
from picamera import PiCamera
import time 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


###SERVO SETUP###
servoPIN_x = 17
servoPIN_y = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN_x, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN_y, GPIO.OUT)
px = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN_x, 50)
py = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN_y, 50)
position_x = 7.5
position_y = 7.5
px.start(position_x)
py.start(position_y)

x_gain = 0.1#0.01 - 5.00
y_gain = 0.3#0.01 - 5.00

xon = True
yon = True

###CAMERA SETUP##
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
raw_capture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
time.sleep(0.1)


###VIDEO CAPTURE LOOP### 
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(raw_capture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    #cv2 video init
    image = frame.array
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#color parameters
low_red = np.array([161,155,84])
high_red = np.array([179,255,255])

#find color
red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_red, high_red)#create black/white mask for all reds
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(red_mask,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)#find different red contours
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x:cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)#sort contours from largest to smallest

#set line x/y var to center
x_medium=320
y_medium=240

#loop sets x/y_medium
for cnt in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    y_medium = int((y+y+h)/2)
    x_medium = int((x+x+w)/2)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    break

#draw lines
cv2.line(image,(x_medium,0),(x_medium,480), (0,255,0),2)
cv2.line(image,(0,y_medium),(640,y_medium), (0,255,0),2)

#cv2.imshow('mask', red_mask)
#show regular frame
cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
raw_capture.truncate(0)

#quit 
if key == ord("q"):
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    px.stop()
    py.stop
    break



#servoX travels to place postion_x in center frame
if not xon and x_medium != 320:
    px.start(position_x)


if x_medium > 320:
    position_x = position_x - x_gain
    
elif x_medium < 320:
    position_x = position_x + x_gain
elif x_medium == 320:
    position_x = position_x
    xon = False
else:
    position_x = 7.5
    
if xon:
    px.ChangeDutyCycle(position_x)
else:
    px.stop



px.stop()
py.stop()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
exit(0)
```

Comment: *"I have a 470uf capacitor and an external power supply"* -> A diagram and/or photo of your wiring would be helpful, as well as the servo make/model.

Answer (score 1):

You are using software PWM to generate the servo pulses.  The timing will be jittery and cause the servo to fidget (this will likely cause the servo to overheat and shorten its life).

I suggest you use hardware timed PWM.

The simplest method is likely to be using pigpio.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import pigpio

S1=17
S2=18

servos=[S1, S2]
width=[1500, 1500]
step=[10, -10]

MIN_WIDTH=1000
MAX_WIDTH=2000

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
   exit()

while True:

   try:

      for s in range(2):
         print(servos[s], width[s])
         pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos[s], width[s])

         width[s] += step[s]

         if width[s]<MIN_WIDTH or width[s]>MAX_WIDTH:
            step[s] = -step[s]
            width[s] += step[s]

      time.sleep(0.1)

   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      break

print("\nTidying up")

for s in range(2):
   pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos[s], 0)

pi.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a single-parameter controller, where the error is multiplied by a factor (`x_gain`?) and applied to the servo input. What you need is a PI (proportional/integral) controller, where the P factor is much smaller and only affects the reaction speed, but the position error is accumulated over time and multiplied by an I factor, which in turn affects the precision.

Then the tuning becomes easy: increase the P factor until the shaking appears, then reduce it a little bit to make the shaking go away and keep increasing the I factor until you reach your desired precision.